# Is it possible to merge changes from old repository to a duplicated repository?

Tags: github

In GitHub, Is it possible to merge changes from old repository to a duplicated repository? If it is possible, what are the steps involved?

These are the [steps](https://help.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/duplicating-a-repository) I'd follow to duplicate a repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you should do it local.

So

1. Clone you repo locally. `git clone <url>`
2. Added a second remote for the old repository `git remote add old <url>`
3. Checkout a branch from your second remote and push it to the first.
   E.g. something like this:

   ```
   git fetch old
   git checkout old/mybranch
   git checkout -b newname
   git push origin -u
   ```